# How do I apply a browser-position to my code?

Tags: javascript, css, position

Earlier today I asked a question about my webpage being very 'jumpy'.

I've posted a test version of my webpage here: http://armandbakx.nl/

And a codepen can be viewed here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GpmQoY

```
$('img').on('click', show);
$('.overlay').on('click', hide);

function show(){   
   $('.scroll-container').eq($(this).parent().index()).addClass('show');
   $('.content-container').addClass('no-scroll');
   $('.overlay').addClass('opacity');
}

function hide() {
   $('.scroll-container').removeClass('show');
   $('.content-container').removeClass('no-scroll');
   $('.overlay').removeClass('opacity');
}
```

The idea of the page is that you click on an image (in this case a red square), resulting in a hidden container showing, which can be scrolled through, containing more information and images about this image.

However, when you click one of the squares, and the container and overlay show, the other images (squares) move. It was suggested to me that in my show function I should try and keep track of the position my browser was in when this container opened. Then in my hide function, return the browser to that position.

Truth to be told, I am not good with JavaScript AT ALL, so I'm pretty much clueless as to how I should apply this. I'm having more issues with this webpage and I have to fix them fast, hence I'm asking again. Could anybody help me with this?

Comment: Can you post your CSS? particularly the CSS behind 'show'?

Comment: This is the only .css for 'show': .show {
  display: block;
}

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this. When I click the red square, I see an overlay instantaneous, with no jumpyness. When I click out of the overlay, it goes away, leaving me in whatever spot on the page I've scrolled to. I'm using Chrome 45.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, your squares are moving around because of the .no-scroll class. If I remove it, everything appears to work correctly.

try this:

```
$('img').on('click', show);
$('.overlay').on('click', hide);

function show(){   
   $('.scroll-container').eq($(this).parent().index()).addClass('show');
   $('.overlay').addClass('opacity');
}

function hide() {
   $('.scroll-container').removeClass('show');
   $('.overlay').removeClass('opacity');
}
```

Comment: I just tested it and it works great in the sense that it keeps the other images in place, which is great! The only thing I notice now is that the background scrolls along with the container, which it didn't do before, what did you change to achieve this, and can it be undone?

Comment: Since your example code only has a white background I didn't notice. you might play with your background styling, there are css options to keep a background fixed vs scrolling with the page.

Answer (score 0):

In your show function, you can retrieve the scroll position before the Text is shown.

```
scrollHeight = $(document).scrollTop();
```

In your hide function, set the scroll position to the value you got previously.

```
$(document).scrollTop( scrollHeight );
```

Comment: Applying this did exactly what I wanted it to. Now the only thing I'm looking for, same as with _denodster's_ answer, is how it does this, while keeping the red images in the background fixed. Only the scroll-container should scroll when it's active, not the background with it.

Comment: Put your "scroll-container" within a div
Give the div an overflow property of hidden and then give your scroll container an overflow property of scroll y